# Unable to build/assemble grails project with '''gradle''' command Artifact 'org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11@jar' not found

Tags: java, grails, gradle, groovy

I have a grails project with below-mentioned configuration

| Grails Version: 3.2.3
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_121

I'm able to build & assemble the project with grails assemble & grails run-app command.

But getting issue with gradle build

My grails version:-
grailsVersion=3.2.3
gradleWrapperVersion=3.0

Error stacktrace:-

```html
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:49)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:27)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:82)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:463)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.updateClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:36)
 at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:118)
 at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
 at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:466)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
 at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
 at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:78)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:130)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:442)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:437)
 at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:40)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
 at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
 at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
 at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
 at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
 at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
 at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Artifact 'org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11@jar' not found.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:38)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolve(ExternalResourceResolver.java:494)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ExternalResourceResolverAdapter.resolve(ExternalResourceResolverAdapter.java:39)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository$2.run(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:58)
 at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:49)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.resolve(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:56)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LocalModuleVersionRepository.resolve(LocalModuleVersionRepository.java:35)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.IvyContextualiser$1.invoke(IvyContextualiser.java:44)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.resolve(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain$ModuleVersionRepositoryArtifactResolverAdapter.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:164)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:62)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:39)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:36)
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:130)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:53)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:36)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:34)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:120)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:126)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.getFilesStrict(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:101)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:45)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:79)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
 ... 36 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Please let me know if you need any info from my side

Answer (score 0):

My previous version of Gradle was 1.4. I 've upgraded the version to 3.5. 
Now, This issue is automatically resolved